# Xcode: Random Contextless Hexadecimal Output to Console

Tags: ios, xcode, logging

I have an iOS app developed in Xcode. When running my app in the simulator, I'm getting some random hexadecimal output in the console log when navigating to one particular view controller (example below). It does not happen when navigating to other controllers, and I don't see anything jumping out at me that I'm doing differently in this instance, and there are no apparent effects in the simulator of anything being wrong.

Has anyone seen this, can you lend any direction as to what is causing it, or at the very least tell if this is cause for alarm?

The output does not have a timestamp or my app name as a prefix like an NSLog output such as `2020-03-17 14:50:54.387749-0400 AppName`. The output is consistent every time with the same information being logged.

```
0000000A:  0100  4          4          800
00000016:  0101  4          4          800
00000022:  0102  3          6          110
0000002E:  011A  5          8          116
0000003A:  011B  5          8          124
00000046:  0128  3          2            2
00000052:  0131  2         12          132
0000005E:  0132  2         20          144
000000A6:  0100  4          4          256
000000B2:  0101  4          4          256
000000BE:  0102  3          6          266
000000CA:  0103  3          2            6
000000D6:  0106  3          2            6
000000E2:  0115  3          2            3
000000EE:  0201  4          4          272
000000FA:  0202  4          4         4506
0000000A:  0100  4          4          800
00000016:  0101  4          4          800
00000022:  0102  3          6          110
0000002E:  011A  5          8          116
0000003A:  011B  5          8          124
00000046:  0128  3          2            2
00000052:  0131  2         12          132
0000005E:  0132  2         20          144
000000A6:  0100  4          4          256
000000B2:  0101  4          4          256
000000BE:  0102  3          6          266
000000CA:  0103  3          2            6
000000D6:  0106  3          2            6
000000E2:  0115  3          2            3
000000EE:  0201  4          4          272
000000FA:  0202  4          4         4506
0000000A:  0100  4          4          800
00000016:  0101  4          4          800
00000022:  0102  3          6          110
0000002E:  011A  5          8          116
0000003A:  011B  5          8          124
00000046:  0128  3          2            2
00000052:  0131  2         12          132
0000005E:  0132  2         20          144
000000A6:  0100  4          4          256
000000B2:  0101  4          4          256
000000BE:  0102  3          6          266
000000CA:  0103  3          2            6
000000D6:  0106  3          2            6
000000E2:  0115  3          2            3
000000EE:  0201  4          4          272
000000FA:  0202  4          4         4506
0000000A:  0100  4          4          800
00000016:  0101  4          4          800
00000022:  0102  3          6          110
0000002E:  011A  5          8          116
0000003A:  011B  5          8          124
00000046:  0128  3          2            2
00000052:  0131  2         12          132
0000005E:  0132  2         20          144
000000A6:  0100  4          4          256
000000B2:  0101  4          4          256
000000BE:  0102  3          6          266
000000CA:  0103  3          2            6
000000D6:  0106  3          2            6
000000E2:  0115  3          2            3
000000EE:  0201  4          4          272
000000FA:  0202  4          4         4506
```

Comment: There are at least two candidates for this sort of logging: `print` statements and (far less likely) Xcode breakpoints configured to log a message and continue execution. Neither of them include that `NSLog`/`os_log` style prefix...

Comment: If you’re confident that this isn’t generated by your code (and this output looks specific enough that I’d suspect you’d recognize it if you ever wrote code or added breakpoints to do this), look at any third party libraries that you might be using. Often they might have `print` statements of their own. Some libraries even have settings to configure how much diagnostic logging is done.